# Product and Inventory Management

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am software engineer student and i am developing an inventory Management System and in need of help for the following.

For an instance lets assume there's a tshirt which has a lot of variants

Ex : **BrandA Tshirt Men's**

*Variations*

-- Red Colour Medium

-- Blue Colour Medium

My question is how do i add the variants to a product into the database?

I do have a logic in mind but i still want to clarify the doubts

Comment: Welcome to SO. This sort of question is far too broad for SO which is a Q&A site for specific programming questions. I'd recommend asking in a forum, subreddit or similar environment. Flagging to close as too broad.

Comment: The logic in your mind is good. Go with it.